# Dealing/Fixing the Ploop issue with OpenVZ -- relclaiming lost space

Tags: virtualization, filesystems, openvz, ploop

So OpenVZ Ploop has a bug where if users add then delete files the space becomes unclaimed and the disk eventually runs out of space. Now there is a script that fixes that(included below). However, surely there is a better way then running this script daily to fix the problem without having to changes virtualizations.

Basically, the question is: Is there a more ideal way to reclaim lost space other then running a script every so often? (I am assuming that the script will cause load issues?).

Offtopic: Why does ploop have this issue and not other virtualizations?

```
#!/bin/bash
# compact.sh by Devon of ByteOnSite for OpenVZ
# SETTINGS

# Config Directory
CFG="/tmp"

# VZ Partition
VZ=`cat $CFG/compact.vzdir 2>/dev/null`
# Run Compact Automatically Every X Runs. Default: 96 runs, if run every 15 minutes this is every 24 hours.
ONXRUNS=`cat $CFG/compact.onxruns 2>/dev/null`
# Minimum Free Space in MB.  Will attempt to compact if free space drops below this.  Default: automatically generated, 5% free space.
MINFREE=`cat $CFG/compact.minfree 2>/dev/null`
# Email Address
EMAIL=`cat $CFG/compact.email 2>/dev/null`
# Log enabled
LOG=`cat $CFG/compact.logging 2>/dev/null`

# END SETTINGS

# DEFAULT SETTINGS

# Default VZ Partition
if [ ! $VZ ]; then
    VZ="/vz"
    echo $VZ > $CFG/compact.vzdir
fi
# Default ONXRUNS
if [ ! $ONXRUNS ]; then
    ONXRUNS=96
    echo $ONXRUNS > $CFG/compact.onxruns
fi
# Default MINFREE (5% of Total Partition)
if [ ! $MINFREE ]; then
    MINFREE=$[`df -PBM $VZ | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}' | cut -f1 -dM`/20]
    echo $MINFREE > $CFG/compact.minfree
fi
if [ ! $LOG ]; then
    LOG=1
    echo $LOG > $CFG/compact.logging
fi

# END DEFAULT SETTINGS

# LOGIC

FREESPACE=`df -PBM $VZ | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' | cut -f1 -dM`

# DEBUG
if [ "$1" = "debug" ]; then
    echo "CFG: $CFG"
    echo "VZ: $VZ"
    echo "FREESPACE: ${FREESPACE}MB"
    echo "MINFREE: ${MINFREE}MB"
    echo "ONXRUNS: $ONXRUNS"
    echo "LOG: $LOG"
    echo "EMAIL: $EMAIL"
    if [ ! -f "/bin/mail" ]; then
        echo "MAILX: NOT FOUND. EMAILS WON'T BE SENT ON WARNING"
    fi
    exit 0
fi
# END DEBUG

i=`cat $CFG/compact.count`
if [ ! "$i" ] || [ "$i" -eq $ONXRUNS ]; then
    i=1
fi
if [ $i -eq 1 ] || [ $FREESPACE -lt $MINFREE ]; then
    # Run compact for every VPS
    stdout="/dev/null"
    if [ $LOG -eq 1 ]; then
        stdout="$CFG/compact.log"
    fi
    for veid in `vzlist -H -o veid`
    do
        date=`date`
        echo "Starting compact on VEID $veid at $date.." >$stdout 2>&1
        vzctl compact $veid >$stdout 2>&1
    done
    # Check disk space again
    FREESPACE=`df -PBM $VZ | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' | cut -f1 -dM`
    if [ $FREESPACE -lt $MINFREE ]; then
        message="Unable to compact containers enough to reduce free space below MINFREE levels. Free Space: $FREESPACE MB."
        echo $message | wall
        hostname=`hostname`
        if [ $EMAIL ]; then
            echo $message | mail -s "Compact failure on $hostname" $EMAIL
        fi
    fi
fi

# Increase count
i=$[$i+1]
echo $i > $CFG/compact.count

# END LOGIC
exit 0
#
#
# pulled from SolidShellSecurity.com Script Repository where clients submit scripts for other clients. 
#
#
```

Comment: What is your question _for us_? It sounds like you have a question for Parallels.

Comment: Well it's not really parallels per-say as it is OpenVZ in general. Will edit for a question. :)